# What does で mean when ordering food/drinks?

Tags: particle-で

In a TV show, I heard the following exchange:

> Man: 生ビール
>
> Izakaya owner: 大？中？
>
> Man: 大で

I thought で was used to talk about location, so I'm a bit confused.

What does で mean in this case?

Comment: There is a very interesting poll conducted by NHK regarding how different age groups "feel" about this 「で」,  especially when selecting an item from a huge list of things.  The graph at the bottom of this page looks stunning.  https://www.nhk.or.jp/bunken/summary/kotoba/term/167.html

Comment: So what would be the 'safe' way to indicate a large beer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This "で" is used for decision-making situation.

For example, you and your friends are talking about when to go traveling.

> Your friend: いつ旅行に行く？来週もしくは再来週？

When are we going on trip? Next week or the week after next week?

> Me: 再来週で。

Okay, then. Let us leave on the next week after next week.

Your example sentence also describes which one to choose large or medium size of beer. Then, Man chose large one.

> Man: 生ビール
>
> Izakaya owner: 大？中？
>
> Man: 大で

Comment: Do you know if the use of the で　esp in the trip example is used locally somewhere, or is it all over Japan? While I feel like the writer of the blog mentioned below, I have not been that much exposed to the saying. http://banban.hatenablog.com/entry/%E3%80%8C%E3%81%A7%E3%80%81%E3%81%84%E3%81%84%E3%80%8D%E3%82%92%E4%BD%BF%E3%82%8F%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84

Comment: @Tuomo What you are asking  "でいい" and "で" seem different things to me. You might need to make question here though., I will answere here. "再来週でいいよ" means I make up mind going on trip on the week after next week at this moment but I might change my mind. in the future. "再来週がいいよ"  means I would like to go on trip on the week after next week.

Comment: Thank you! I will need to digest this further (while acknowleging that my comment was a bit misleading), that is, yes, the trip example was not about でいい (while, I think that beer example may have been), but I still personally wouldn't use で in either of them.